# Polygon to Multipolygon

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a database in PostgreSQL / PostGIS with polygons so how can i merge some polygons into multipolygons of the database using it as QGIS Layer?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`st_collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html) to aggregate polygons into multipolygons:

```
 with src as (
   select 1 as gp, st_geomFromText('Polygon((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))') geom 
   union 
   select 1, st_geomFromText('Polygon((10 10, 10 11, 11 11, 11 10, 10 10))') 
   union 
   select 2, st_geomFromText('Polygon((20 20, 20 21, 21 21, 21 20, 20 20))')
   )
 select gp, 
        st_asText(st_collect(geom)) 
 from src 
 group by gp;

 gp |                                st_astext
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0)),((10 10,10 11,11 11,11 10,10 10)))
  2 | MULTIPOLYGON(((20 20,20 21,21 21,21 20,20 20)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function ST_Multi
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html

```
WITH src as (
   SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0),
                                   (10 10, 10 11, 11 11, 11 10, 10 10))') geom) 
   SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Multi(geom)) from src group by geom;
```

result:

`MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0),(10 10,10 11,11 11,11 10,10 10)))`